# How to verify typeorm update by createQueryBuilder() NESTJS MySql typeORM

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

im using NEST JS and typeorm on MySql database. Update code:

```
   const doneReport = await createQueryBuilder()
  .update(ReportAd)
  .set({ status: reportStatus.done })
  .where('id = :id', { id: idReport })
  .execute()
  .then(result => {
    console.log('RESULT', result);
    return result;
  });
```

When i update data using createQueryBuilder() and putted data is valid (id) i always get back result like:

```
RESULT UpdateResult { generatedMaps: [], raw: [], affected: 1 }
```

So, i cant recoginize if this record has been changed, or in this example 'status' hasn't changed. Only one option load object from db and compare objects before and after?

if I want throw invalid id error always ill always get back somethink like this?

```
RESULT UpdateResult { generatedMaps: [], raw: [], affected: 0 }
```

Comment: Your question title is very clear. However, I don't follow what you have explained in the description. Can't you use the `affected` property of `result` to determine whether the record is updated or not?

Comment: I mean, when i use correct sql statement to update record, when accuatly update statement will not change anythink (0 changes in databasse) but it returns "affected : 1".
I just wanna ask, is poosible to verify or create other query to know in query result is anythink changed?